# r lm vectorised control variables

Tags: r, lm

I often have to write long equations with controls variables that do not change.

For instance, `hp` is my variable of interest (`x`) that change between models and `vs + am + gear + carb` are my controls

```
lm(disp ~ hp + vs + am + gear + carb, mtcars)
```

Then my `x` is `drat` and then `wt` but my controls are the same.

```
lm(disp ~ drat + vs + am + gear + carb, mtcars)
lm(disp ~ wt + vs + am + gear + carb, mtcars)
```

I would find it quite useful sometimes to be able to reduce the equations to something like

```
y = 'disp' 
x = 'hp'
controls = 'vs + am + gear + carb'

lm(y ~ x + controls, mtcars)
```

Any idea how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below constructs a string formula (with a small edit to @ZheyuanLi's comment) to feed to `lm` and also uses the `map` function from `purrr` (a `tidyverse` package) to create a separate model for each variable in the `x` vector. Each element of the list `models` contains the model object and the name of the element is the value of `x` that was used in the model formula.

```
library(tidyverse)

y = 'disp' 
x = c('hp','wt')
controls=c("vs","am","gear","carb")

models = map(setNames(x,x), 
             ~ lm(paste(y, paste(c(.x, controls), collapse="+"), sep="~"), 
                  data=mtcars))

map(models, summary)
```

> ```
> $hp
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = paste(y, paste(c(.x, controls), collapse = "+"), 
>     sep = "~"), data = mtcars)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -85.524 -19.153   1.109  14.957 115.804 
>
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) 261.9238    73.2477   3.576   0.0014 ** 
> hp            1.2021     0.2453   4.900 4.38e-05 ***
> vs          -63.7135    26.5957  -2.396   0.0241 *  
> am          -56.0468    30.7338  -1.824   0.0797 .  
> gear        -31.6231    23.4816  -1.347   0.1897    
> carb        -14.3237    10.1169  -1.416   0.1687    
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 47.97 on 26 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8743,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8502 
> F-statistic: 36.18 on 5 and 26 DF,  p-value: 6.547e-11
>
>
> $wt
>
> Call:
> lm(formula = paste(y, paste(c(.x, controls), collapse = "+"), 
>     sep = "~"), data = mtcars)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -74.153 -36.993  -2.097  30.616 102.331 
>
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept)   28.875    108.220   0.267  0.79172    
> wt            88.577     18.810   4.709 7.25e-05 ***
> vs           -92.669     25.186  -3.679  0.00107 ** 
> am            -3.734     34.662  -0.108  0.91503    
> gear          -4.688     25.271  -0.186  0.85427    
> carb          -8.455      9.662  -0.875  0.38955    
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 48.88 on 26 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8695,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8445 
> F-statistic: 34.66 on 5 and 26 DF,  p-value: 1.056e-10
> ```

Comment: very cool, thanks, you can also add `tidy` to be fully `tidyverse `, `map(models, tidy)`